# Indication of a seated bead

Tags: motorcycle, wheels, tires

Does a tube have to 'pop' for the bead to set?

I've changed the tire, pumped to 30 PSI. The line on the tire looks even across the circumference, but there was no 'pop'. Should I pump it up further?

I've got a tubed 21" tire.

Comment: is the tire seated against the rim wall? if not then increase the pressure...